# How to write a Copy macro for excel?

Tags: excel, vba, copy

I looking for a macro which is copying from column D to column F if D is(blank) than copy from C to F if empty copy from B to F if empty copy from A to F and the after delete the copied cells.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please check out the following guidelines to asking questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, in particular the part about "Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work...". You will generally find you get much better answers if people can see if that you have tried to solve the problem yourself.

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started:

```
Sub CopyCol()
    If Application.CountA(Range("D:D")) > 0 Then
        Range("F:F").Value = Range("D:D").Value
        Range("D:D").FormulaR1C1 = ""
    ElseIf Application.CountA(Range("C:C")) > 0 Then
        Range("F:F").Value = Range("C:C").Value
        Range("C:C").FormulaR1C1 = ""
    ElseIf Application.CountA(Range("B:B")) > 0 Then
        Range("F:F").Value = Range("B:B").Value
        Range("B:B").FormulaR1C1 = ""
    ElseIf Application.CountA(Range("A:A")) > 0 Then
        Range("F:F").Value = Range("A:A").Value
        Range("A:A").FormulaR1C1 = ""
    End If
End Sub
```

Note that it will pick up columns with spaces or other non-visible items.  I'm assuming you just have plain data and the entire column is truly empty.